# slidetoggle not removing when page size changes

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

Hi all i have got my repsonsive menu working at mobile level.

when the website changes size the slideToggle does not get removed and I am not sure how to make this happen.

```
$(".click").click(function () 
$('#menu').slideToggle("veryslow"); });`
```

Comment: if you want you can check the live code @ www.rrm.jonfullerwebdesign.co.uk

Comment: Just what is there.  I am unsure why the function when it is hiding when i resize window if it is toggled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're approaching this in the wrong way. You need to have 2 menus ideally, one for mobiles/tablets and another for desktop sites. Trigger the dropdown (like you have now) on mobiles with jQuery, but on desktops, hide the mobile navigation and show the normal desktop navigation.

What you have above is just constantly telling the menu to slide open/close. You aren't specifying at what point it needs to do something else. Responsive is 99% CSS 3 and 1% jQuery to do the slide open and close.

I hope this helps!